# Embedded Linux poll() returns constantly

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I have a particular problem. Poll keeps returning when I know there is nothing to read.

So the setup it as follows, I have 2 File Descriptors which form part of a `fd` set that poll watches. One is for a Pin high to low change (GPIO). The other is for a proxy input. The problem occurs with the Proxy Input.

The order of processing is: start main functions; it will then poll; write data to proxy; poll will break; accept the data; send the data over SPI; receiving slave device, signals that it wants to send ack, by Dropping GPIO low; `poll()` senses this drop and reacts;
Infinite `POLLIN`s  :(

IF I have no timeout on the Poll function, the program works perfectly. The moment I include a timeout on the Poll. The Poll returns continuously. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
while(1)
{
    memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));

    fdset[0].fd = gpio_fd;
    fdset[0].events = POLLPRI; // POLLPRI - There is urgent data to read 

    fdset[1].fd = proxy_rx;
    fdset[1].events = POLLIN; // POLLIN   - There is data to read

    rc = poll(fdset, nfds, 1000);//POLL_TIMEOUT);
            
    if (rc < 0)     // Error
    {
        printf("\npoll() failed/Interrupted!\n");
    }
    else if (rc == 0)       // Timeout occurred
    {
        printf(" poll() timeout\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fdset[1].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            printf("fdset[1].revents & POLLIN\n");
            if ((resultR =read(fdset[1].fd,command_buf,10))<0)
            {                                   
                printf("Failed to read Data\n");
            }
            if (fdset[0].revents & POLLPRI)
            //if( (gpio_fd != -1) && (FD_ISSET(gpio_fd, &err)))
            {
                lseek(fdset[0].fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // Read from the start of the file
                len = read(fdset[0].fd, reader, 64);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that is the gist of my code.

I have also used GDB and while debugging, I found that the GPIO descriptor was set with `revents = 0x10`, which means that an error occurred and that `POLLPRI` also occurred.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021146/poll2-doesnt-empty-the-event-queue), something similar was addressed. But I do read all the time whenever I get `POLLIN`. It is a bit amazing, that this problem **only** occurs when I include the `timeout`, if I replace the poll `timeout` with `-1`, it works perfectly.

Comment: Although I don't think it's the cause of this particular problem, be aware that the `sysfs` interface to GPIO only detects edges when there is a thread blocked on in `poll()` or `select()` - it doesn't buffer them until the next call.  Unless you are absolutely sure (by protocol design and implementation) that you'll always be blocked when the ACK appears,  there's potential for a race condition and getting into a state where you never receive another one.   My solution to this is a similar scenario to yours was a kernel mode driver.

Comment: Well its been seven years since I first posted this. Wow. We did refactor this piece of code make it simpler. The main route cause of this eventually turned out to be a driver issue from the device connected, where they were unable to clear the flags. As was pointed out by Marko above there is no buffer and therefore introduces edge cases where things can be missed too (encountered this problem much later too)

Answer (score 0):

When `poll` fails (returning -1) you should do something with `errno`, perhaps thru `perror`; and your `nfds` (the second argument to `poll`) is not set, but it should be the constant 2.

Probably the GCC compiler would have given a warning, at least with all warnings enabled (`-Wall`), about `nfds` not being set.

<sup>(I'm guessing that `nfds` being uninitialized might be some "random" large value.... So the kernel might be polling other "random" file descriptors, those in your  `fdset`  after index 2...)</sup>

BTW, you could `strace` your program. And using the `fdset` name is a bit confusing (it could refer to `select(2)`).

Comment: poll() doesnt fail, however I did use the perror idea and print out the error that was popping up (I have been receiving :Device or resource busy for the GPIO File descriptor). nfds is initially set to 2 in main, didnt include that part, sorry. Also, I see it happens as soon as I allow the other device to alter the GPIO. Still quite perplexing

Answer (score -1):

Assuming I fixed your formatting properly in your question, it looks like you have a missing `}` after the `POLLIN` block and the next `if()` that checks the `POLLPRI`. It would possibly work better this way:

```
    if (fdset[1].revents & POLLIN)
    {
        printf("fdset[1].revents & POLLIN\n");
        if ((resultR =read(fdset[1].fd,command_buf,10))<0)
        {                                   
            printf("Failed to read Data\n");
        }
    }
    if (fdset[0].revents & POLLPRI)
    //if( (gpio_fd != -1) && (FD_ISSET(gpio_fd, &err)))
    {
        lseek(fdset[0].fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // Read from the start of the file
        len = read(fdset[0].fd, reader, 64);
    }
```

Although you can do whatever you want with indentation in C/C++/Java/JavaScript, not doing it right can bite you really hard. Hopefully, I'm wrong and your original code was correct.

Another one I often see: People not using the `{ ... }` at all and end up writing code like:

```
if(expr) do_a; do_b;
```

and of course, `do_b;` will be executed all the time, whether `expr` is true or false... and although you could fix the above with a comma like so:

```
if(expr) do_a, do_b;
```

the only safe way to do it right is to use the brackets:

```
if(expr)
{
    do_a;
    do_b;
}
```

Always make sure your indentation is perfect and write small functions so you can see that it is indeed perfect.